# Templates, Routes, and URL segments

Tags: templating, routes, segments

In EE, if there was a template `/foo/bar.html`, one could access the contents of that template by going to either `example.com/foo/bar` or `example.com/foo/bar/more/segments/here`. The additional URL segments didn't prevent EE from loading the most-accurately-matching template.

Moving over to Craft, `bar` is now an entry's slug. The section for that entry is properly set up with the "Entry URI Format" and "Template" pointing to `foo/{slug}` and `foo/_entry.html`, respectively. Is there a way to get the same "most-accurate" template-matching behavior in Craft? Perhaps with routes? I would want the `{{ entry }}` variable to be automatically available for either URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no. 
Yes it is possible to include as many additional segments to **selected** routes and it's even possible to achieve what you want but it might become resource heavy and you would need to handle the entire routing on your own.

#### Channels

If it's for a channel with a set `URI` format like `foo/{slug}` you can implement a route like

```php
Event::on(
    UrlManager::class,
    UrlManager::EVENT_REGISTER_SITE_URL_RULES,
    function(RegisterUrlRulesEvent $event) {
        $event->rules[] = [
            'pattern'  => 'foo/<uri:\S+>/<additionals:\S+>',
            'route'    => 'your-module/your-controller/route',
            'defaults' => [
                'additionals' => ''
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

So all your urls like `foo/{slug}` as well as `foo/{slug}/bar/whatever`  will be routed to your controller `YourController::actionRoute` with the parameters

```php
public function actionRoute(string $uri, string $additionals = null)
{
    $element = Craft::$app->getElements()->getElementByUri($uri);
    $template = (new Query())->select('template')
        ->from('sections_sites')
        ->where(['=', 'siteId', $element->site->id])
        ->andWhere(['=', 'sectionId', $element->sectionId])
        ->scalar();

    return $this->renderTemplate($template, ['entry' => $element]);
}
```

**Note** keep in mind this will only work if the `uri` format is rather simple like `foo/{slug}` it won't really work for things like `foo/{author}/{category.id}/{slug}/{title}` you'll need the rule mentioned in "structures" for it

#### Singles

If it's for singles you can do it dynamically

```php
try {
    $uris = (new Query())
        ->select('uriFormat')
        ->from('sections_sites')-
        ->where(['=', 'siteId', Craft::$app->getSites()->getCurrentSite()->id])
        ->andWhere(['=', 'sectionId', [array of your section ids])
        ->column();
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    $uris = [];
}

if (empty($uris) === false) {
    $event->rules[] = [
        'pattern'  => '<uri:(' . implode('|', $uris) . ')>' . '/<additional:\S+>',
        'route'    => 'module/controller/action',
        'defaults' => [
            'additional' => ''
        ]
    ];
}
```

#### Structures

For structures it's not that easy... You would need to recursively remove one segment and try to search for a matching route if there is one, use it, otherwise remove the next one.

**Attention pseudocode**

```PHP
$path = get your full path
while($element === null){
    $path = $path - lastSegment;
    $element = Craft::$app->getElements()->getElementByUri($path);
}  
// attach the route `path` as you can see above
```

However I would **not** suggest the code above since it will search for a matching element for each segment for **every** request. I would highly recommend to include many conditions around it like `Craft::$app->getRequest()->isSiteRequest() === true` and `$request->isAjaxRequest() === false` and so on to reduce the amount of queries as much as possible